# CMake can't find FindGLEW.cmake

Tags: cmake, cocos2d-x, glew

Ubuntu12.04
Cocos2d-x-3.4
When I buid the test project,there are some errors:

```
It appears you are builing natively for Linux with GCC
-- OpenGL include dirs: /usr/include
**CMake Error at cmake/Modules/CocosBuildHelpers.cmake:44** (find_package):
  **Could not find module FindGLEW.cmake or a configuration file for package
  GLEW**.

  Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find FindGLEW.cmake or set GLEW_DIR to the
  directory containing a CMake configuration file for GLEW.  The file will
  have one of the following names:

    GLEWConfig.cmake
    glew-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:159 (cocos_find_package)
```

I have checked the path `cmake/Modules/`. There is no `FindGLEW.cmake`  file. But I don't know where I can get it, or how I can fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

- Some packages that are aware of CMake provide their own Find*.cmake. For example Eigen does so. By having a quick look into the GLEW sources, they don't ship their own find package macro.
- Sometimes the projects relying on external libraries ship their own Find*.cmake for the external dependency. A quick look at their repository reveals, they ship it neither.

But CMake 2.8.10 or newer contains the test, see [its documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/module/FindGLEW.html). The test was improved in 3.1. You can update your CMake installation and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it.But,I haven't understood it clearly.
I make a file "FindGLEW.cmake" in the path "cmake/Modules"
The content of that file just like the url said.
http://www-i8.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/svnrepo/OpenFlipper/branches/Free/cmake/FindGLEW.cmake

Comment: You have an outdated (with respect to cocos2d) CMake, it does not ship the FindGLEW.cmake. By putting it into cmake/Modules CMake will find and use the file. I would advice you to update your CMake version, unless you are not able to do so.

Comment: I cannot change my (old) version of cmake on this system and still need a fix. So I upvoted this idea. thx

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem i.e. `cmake` not finding "FindGlew.cmake" with the following error:
`By not providing "FindGlew.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project...`

Which was weird because I did have that module... Only it was called `FindGLEW.cmake` (residing in `/usr/share/cmake/Modules/` for Fedora/Linux).

And so, I had to make a link to `FindGlew.cmake` using `sudo ln -sf /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindGLEW.cmake /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindGlew.cmake`

To be on the safe side I run a small script I whipped up which produces a list of all permutations of uppercase and lowercase letters in `FindGlew` and makes links to all of them. Just a precaution when dealing with time-wasters to-be-programmers aspriring to create the bigger-and-better `make`. Yeah right...

p.s. If `FindGLEW.cmake` does not exist in your system then you need to upgrade `cmake` and/or install additional module `glew-devel`.

Comment: This answer has been edited out (=CENSORED) to remove "chatty part" by someone who signs with: ```I hate Autotools so much that I started to tranform a large project to CMake.``` The cut-out part reads ```Three years on and still same problems ... But first let me declare that working with cmake/CMAKE/Cmake/CMake/CMaKe is not my choice. If I had a choice I would keep away from it.``` Maybe I am chatty but I hate wasting my time. I hope this helps others.